# Правильно ли я понимаю одно из преимуществ сверточной нейронной сети над обычной для классификации изображений

Tags: машинное-обучение, нейронные-сети

В глубоком обучении новичок, не судите строго.
Так допустим я хочу использовать обычную нейронную сеть для классификации изображений, человек ли это или нет.

[image: ![введите сюда описание изображения]

Картинка всего имеет допустим 680 пикселей. На нейроны входного слоя поступают значение пикселей, нейроны скрытого слоя же, выявляют некоторые черты лица, и нейрон отмеченный зеленым цветом допустим отвечает за поиск носа.(допустим)

И допустим при обучении этой нейронной сети, большинство пикселей на которых был расположен нос это пиксели 50-75(допустим), это значит, что веса между нейронами 50-75 входного слоя и нейроном скрытого слоя отвечающий за нос(зеленый) намного больше чем между другими нейронами входного слоя и этим нейроном скрытого слоя.

В таком случае если мы будем хотим классифицировать картинку, которую нейронная сеть раньше не видела, на которой нос находится на других пикселях, допустим 220-245 , в таком случае веса между нейронами 220-245 и нейроном скрытого слоя отвечающего за нахождение носа будут не подходить.

И правильно ли я понимаю, что в этом как раз таки большое преимущество сверточной нейронной сети и использования в ней фильтров, над обычной для классификации изображений?

Answer (score 0):

Немного не так. Вообще если смотреть практическую составляющую, а именно преимущества, то это очевидно скорость операции; это происходит потому, что, условно, мы сворачиваем картинку 512х512 на 32x32; из-за этого в полносвязном слое необходимо находить меньше параметров, а значит, что и искать их можно будет быстрее. Если возвращаться к вашей теории, то необходимо заметить, что свёртка и правда позволяет "разделять влияние" будто бы как на все нейроны, но нужно заметить, что такого понятия, как "этот вес отвечает чётко за этот пиксель" нет именно потому, что изображение сворачивается, и нейрон уже получит на вход результат математических операций над несколькими соседними пикселями.

UPD: Не забудьте о необходимости иметь более широкую выборку при использовании CNN, потому что, как я сказал ранее, нейроном анализируется не один пиксель, а несколько в некоторой степени.